# JointTrajectory time_from_start resets to all zeros after publish()

Tags: ros, rospy, jointtrajectory

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu 12.04
ROS Hydro

I am publishing a JointTrajectory to Gazebo and monitoring the topic using rostopic echo. The data that I publish is different from what gets captured by rostopic echo.  Somehow the "time_from_start" portion of the data gets zeroed out.

A snippet of my code is as follows

```
  # this is where I create and populate the JointTrajectory
  jt = make_trajectory_msg(plan=plan, secs=0.5, dt=0.2, frame_id='base_link' )
  rospy.loginfo("Publishing joint trajectory")
  while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    print jt
    gazebo_command_publisher.publish(jt)
    r.sleep()
```

As you can see, right before I call publish() I print the trajectory.  Here is what the trajectory looks like before the publish()

```
header: 
  seq: 5
  stamp: 
    secs: 0
    nsecs: 0
  frame_id: base_link
joint_names: ['arm_joint_1', 'arm_joint_2', 'arm_joint_3', 'arm_joint_4', 'arm_joint_5']
points: 
  - 
    positions: [0.2792831707677692, 0.4627657000396006, -0.8622084888670658, 0.8533643604717218, 0.1568816032950613]
    velocities: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    accelerations: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    effort: []
    time_from_start: 
      secs: 0.7
      nsecs: 0
```

And here is the trajectory after it is captured by rostopic echo:

```
header: 
  seq: 5
  stamp: 
    secs: 0
    nsecs: 0
  frame_id: base_link
joint_names: ['arm_joint_1', 'arm_joint_2', 'arm_joint_3', 'arm_joint_4', 'arm_joint_5']
points: 
  - 
    positions: [0.2792831707677692, 0.4627657000396006, -0.8622084888670658, 0.8533643604717218, 0.1568816032950613]
    velocities: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    accelerations: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    effort: []
    time_from_start: 
      secs: 0
      nsecs: 0
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/175175/jointtrajectory-time_from_start-resets-to-all-zeros-after-publish()/) by [Rick C NIST](https://answers.ros.org/users/18890/rick-c-nist/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2014-06-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `secs` and `nsecs` fields of a timestamp are integer values, so `secs: 0.7` is getting truncated to zero.

To represent 0.7s, you can either do `time_from_start = rospy.Duration.from_sec(0.7)`, or explicitly set the fields to `secs = 0` and `nsecs = 700000000`

More here http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Time

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2014-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rick C NIST](https://answers.ros.org/users/18890/rick-c-nist/) on 2014-06-27**:
Thank you. That was what I was looking for. I will use the rospy.Duration method from now on.

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2014-06-27**:
You're welcome. I'd appreciate it if you check the answer as valid to so the question shows up as resolved.